# Spring Data JPA Interface-Based Projection Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, projection

I'm working on an application, trying to use interface-based projection. However, im getting following error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.bookstore.bookapi.book.BookRepository.findBooksByAuthor(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.bookstore.bookapi.book.BookRepository.findBooksByAuthor(java.lang.String)! null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.bookstore.bookapi.book.BookRepository.findBooksByAuthor(java.lang.String)! null
```

BookRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
    List<BookDTO> findBooksByAuthor(String author);
   
}
```

BookEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            generator = "book_sequence",
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "book_sequence",
            sequenceName = "book_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String author;
}
```

BookDTO:

```
public interface BookDTO {
    String getName();
}
```

BookService:

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;


    public BookService(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    public List<BookDTO> getBooks(String author) {
        return bookRepository.findBooksByAuthor(author);
    }
}
```

I had already checked out following links:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections


However, could not find the problem. I can use query annotation but i want to learn interface-base projection.

Thanks.

Edit: I was using Spring boot 2.6.3 version, according to answer of @ChinHuang upgraded version to 2.6.4 and solved the issue.

Comment: What Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: Use `findByAuthor` as method name in `BookRepository `

Comment: Is it OK, that in your repository you extend it from `Book`, but you want a `List<BookDTO>`? I think, JPA can't generate the query automatically, because `Book` isn't equal to `BookDTO`. `BookDTO` has no fields at all.

Comment: @ChinHuang spring boot version: 2.6.3

Comment: @Eklavya already tried, but same error

Comment: @ChinHuang I will try upgrade to 2.6.4

Comment: @ChinHuang Thank you, upgrading to 2.6.4 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you method should look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT b.name FROM Book AS b WHERE b.author = :author")
List<BookDTO> findBooksByAuthor(String author);
```

When using a projection, you should return columns matching method names, but `findBooksByAuthor` is returning all columns of `Book` object.